# Find $\liminf a_n$ and $\limsup a_n $

Tags: calculus

> Let $a_n=((-1)^n+1)\cdot n^2$. Find $\liminf a_n$ and $\limsup a_n $.

Usually I would take subsequences such as
$a_{2n} \to \infty$
and $a_{2n+1}$ but in this case it is indefinable. Can i just go ahead and solve this one as a normal limit and finish the exercises or is it something else im missing.

Comment: Hint. $a_{2n+1}$ is identically zero.

Answer (score 1):

$a_{2k+1}=(-1+1)(2k+1)^{2}=0$ for all $k$, so $\liminf_{n}a_{n}\leq 0$.

But $(-1)^{n}+1\geq 0$, so $a_{n}\geq 0$ and hence $\liminf_{n}a_{n}\geq 0$, we have then $\liminf_{n}a_{n}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem in investigating $a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n+1}$ since
$$
{a_{2n}=8n^2\to \infty
\\
a_{2n+1}=0\to 0,
}
$$hence your approach is correct.